# How to delete a published application from Google play store?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to delete an android application from Google playstore but I didn't find where to do that in the google play console.
Does anyone know how to delete an android application from Google play store?

Comment: You can find answer on this [link]( https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201581962-Delete-Your-App-from-Google-Play)

Comment: @PankajMundra your mention way is just to unpublish the app, you can't delete the app once it uploaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot delete app from playstore. you can only unpublish app.

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can only unpublish the app and it will not be visible anymore in PlayStore, so new users will not be able to install it anymore. Note: the application will remain installed for the users who already downloaded it.